# Knockout JS , pushed objects' children property is not bound

Tags: .net, knockout.js

I am working on a .NET application using KnockoutJS. The ViewModel from .NET is mapped using knockout.mapping-latest.js. Here is the [demo](http://survey0323.azurewebsites.net/home/test)

The objects being binded initially works fine, all the "remove" events work. but when a new object (ex. SheetA) is added, the remove event works fine for SheetA, but the events for SheetA's children properties fail (ex. SheetA.LineOfQuestions).

Please click the button "add Sheet" at the bottom of the page, you will see some data being pushed, then click the button "remove group of questions" you will see the exception

*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'remove'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback in AddDummySheet pushes the result JSON object directly into the Sheets observableArray, therefore none of that object model contain observables.

You need to map the result into observables before adding it to the Sheets observable Array

```
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    self.mysurvey.questionarie.Sheets.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(result));
}
```

Comment: I confirm that your code works, but as I read through some of the turtorials online, most of them push json object directly to the observable, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-5 , does it mean that if its data only, it works, but if there is event as well, then it should be observable being push? I am still curious why the event binded to first level object works when Json object is pushed. I do not have the reputation to mark your answer as correct

Comment: Your initial creation of the viewmodel `self.mysurvey = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` will do a deep conversion of the object model to observables.